# Size of columns in QGraphicsGridLayout

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

I have a columns in QGraphicsGridLayout with some content (pyqtgraph's plot, text). Is there any possibility to set width of columns smaller (maybe 0 px) than width of content in column. Content must be cropped and dont stick up in another columns.
setColumnMinimumWidth, setColumnFixedWidth doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by resizing the widgets inside the columns. Making the widgets on one side smaller and bigger on the other resizes the columns to the widgets' size.